# Possibility to use app in LAN and via Internet

Tags: linux, ip, port-forwarding, https

I use web based (https encapsulated) app in my home network and via Internet. The app has dedicated Linux desktop client (I use Mageia ver4 Linux for laptop). Of course server address I have connected to, is different when I am connected to my home LAN directly (laptop and app server are in the same network segment) and when I connect to the home server over internet.
Please advice me. How can I connect to LAN or over Internet without manually running app on desktop with different config file for each connection type?
Or maybe any other solution like changes in my home LAN configuration?
The disadvantages are:
- my home router has no possibility to assign secondary IP address for LAN;
- router uses port redirection for proper access to server app from Internet

Any idea?

Comment: depending of your network, you should be able  to use the public ip from the inside without problem

Comment: In my case, if I try http://<my_domain>.no-ip.org from the inside. web control panel of my router appears. But if I do the same from outside, web site of my server is display. It is because of NAT and port mapping in the router I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your router cannot 'bounce' the connections that arrive from internal network, like explained f.e. in [IPF FAQ](http://www.phildev.net/ipf/IPFprob.html#prob8), so your next best option is to use a proxy on the external network.